# op amp with capacitors

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor

[image]

Why is Cp here not part of the equation?

Comment: Do you know what the voltage at 'x' is?

Comment: That is not a practical circuit, there is no dc path to ground for the input bias current at the op amp's inverting input.

Comment: The name of this circuit is "charge amplifier". You can see what the idea behind it is in this [CD paper](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/278836).

Comment: I agree with @James - Cp probably should be a resistor for that practical reason. IC inputs have some bias current draw, which would "charge up" those capacitors unless there was a path to ground. A large resistor there to ground would effect your gain the least, but would also cause a voltage offset (bias current times resistance value).

Comment: @KD9PDP, If the resistor is connected between the inverting input and ground (in parallel to Cp), there will be no DC negative feedback. That is why, it should be connected in parallel to Cf. Then the circuit will work as a DC voltage follower. BTW Cp represents stray capacitances (like the cabel capacitance) in such applicatiobs as *charge amplifier*.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Ah yeah, I get what you're saying now - yeah, the DC point isn't stabilized, so there should be that resistor. nice point!

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer: because the op amp makes sure node x is always zero volts. It's a virtual ground. The voltage across Cp is always 0, so no current flows. No current, no voltage means no contribution to the transfer function.

Answer (score 0):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following [opamp-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEZanN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_2=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\tag3$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_1=0\tag4$$

So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$\frac{0}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_2-0}{\text{R}_3}\tag3$$

Now, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=-\frac{\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_1}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
V1 = 0;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I2 == I1 + I3, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, 
   I3 == (V2 - V1)/R3}, {I1, I2, I3, V2}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> Vi/R1, I2 -> 0, I3 -> -(Vi/R1), V2 -> -((R3 Vi)/R1)}}
```

My equation was also confirmed using [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice).

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

- $$\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\tag7$$
- $$\text{R}_2=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\tag8$$
- $$\text{R}_3=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_3}\tag9$$

So, we can rewrite the transfer function as:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=-\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_3}}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}}=-\frac{\text{C}_1}{\text{C}_3}\tag{10}$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed explanation. Just realised i missed out V+=V−=V1=0 because i was only going through the question briefly. Nevertheless, thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Jan, You are a beatiful mind... but I would like to ask you, "Do you have any idea about the role of the op-amp here... and in all inverting circuits?" I am just asking you out of curiosity...

Comment: I would have thought replacing the capacitors with resistors would result in an examination of a fundamentally different circuit.